# Chrome app angular js not working

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome-app

I am building a chrome application and have used angularjs in some parts. The script works fine on a web browser but when i use it in my app it does not. Even the controller function is not being invoked.
In my html file i've included the following code

```html
<div name="teaminfo" ng-controller="teamsController">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <th>TeamName</th>
            <th>Wins</th>
        </thead>
        <tr ng-repeat="team in teams">
            <td>
                <input type="text" ng-model="team.teamName">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" ng-model="team.w">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <button class="submit" ng-click="savedata();" type="submit">Save new values</button>
</div>
```

and the javascript

```js
var teamsController = function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("teams.json").success(function (data) {
        $scope.teams = data.teams;
        console.log(data);
        console.log($scope.teams);
    });
    $scope.savedata = function () {
        console.log("savedata function");
        teams = angular.copy($scope.teams);
        console.log(teams);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try adding data-ng-csp on your html node, like: `<html data-ng-app='myApp' data-ng-csp>`

Comment: had you add ng-app? it sometimes easy to forget

Answer (score 0):

have you enabled javascript in your java code

```
 webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```